# Jpush: receiving push notifications in background in Android 6.0

Tags: cordova, background, push-notification, phonegap-plugins, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am using the Jpush plugin for Phonegap (https://github.com/jpush/jpush-phonegap-plugin) in order to receive push notifications. This works well till few minutes after that my app is put in background. I need to reopen my app to be able to receive notifications again. Nevertheless I could see in *Settings->Installed Apps->Running* that 1 process and 1 JPush service are still running.. According to the JPush team, this is due to Android 6's design principles (indeed, I do not meet that problem with Android 5 and iOS).

As I need that my Android app receives notifications while it is in background, I tried to use to use that plugin (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) but I did not see any improvement.. I would like to know if someone knows a solution to prevent Android stopping a Phonegap app that is in background?